# How do I apply a function to each element of list, when it has two inputs? Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

If I have a function with two inputs e.g

```
func x y
```

how do I apply the function to all elements of a list, with only one input being the elements of a list.
so if I have list [1,2,3] and y = 4, how can I use func using each element of the list as x i.e

```
func 1 4
func 2 4
func 3 4
```

And return the answers in a list.

Prelude functions only.

Comment: Why did you tag `recursion`?

Comment: Is your list supposed to be [1,2,3,4] based on your output or do you want add the second argument to itself at the end?

Answer (score 6):

Use the combination of `flip` and `map` function:

```
map (flip func y) x
```

Or as @Jubobs points out, you can do this in a more straightforward fashion:

```
map (\x -> func x y) xs
```

---

Explanation: Let's assume your function `func` has this definition:

```
func :: Int -> String -> Int
func y z = y
```

Now, you can flip it's argument using the flip function:

```
λ> :t (flip func)
(flip func) :: String -> Int -> Int
```

So, now you can apply the second argument directly to it:

```
λ> :t (flip func "dummy")
(flip func "dummy") :: Int -> Int
```

Now, you can use the `map` function to apply all the elements of the list to this function:

```
λ> map (flip func "dummy") [1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: `map (\x -> func x y) xs` should work too, and is perhaps easier to understand.

Comment: @Jubobs Yeah, that would be much easier, will update it.

Comment: @Arthur There is nothing special going on `map (\x -> func x y) xs`: it's the same way of how `map` function works. The `x` corresponds to the individual element of list `xs`. It is being applied to `func` along with `y` on each iteration.